# Split stream and put into list from text file

Tags: java, lambda, split, java-8, java-stream

How can I put all the elements I read from a text file into an `ArrayList < MonitoredData >` using **streams**, where monitoredData class has these 3 private variables: `private Date startingTime, Date finishTime, String activityLabel`;

The text File Activities.txt looks like this:

```
2011-11-28 02:27:59     2011-11-28 10:18:11     Sleeping        
2011-11-28 10:21:24     2011-11-28 10:23:36     Toileting   
2011-11-28 10:25:44     2011-11-28 10:33:00     Showering   
2011-11-28 10:34:23     2011-11-28 10:43:00     Breakfast
```

and so on....

The first 2 strings are separated by one blank space, then 2 tabs, one space again, 2 tabs.

```
String fileName = "D:/Tema 5/Activities.txt";

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        list = (ArrayList<String>) stream
                .map(w -> w.split("\t\t")).flatMap(Arrays::stream) 
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `w.split()` produces an array of 3 strings. Now you need to `map` that array to `MonitoredData`. Either give `MonitoredData` a constructor that takes an array, or have a lambda that calls the constructor

Comment: Do not cast the result of `Collectors.toList()` to `ArrayList`. There is a reason why the declared type is `List` instead of `ArrayList`. There is no guaranty that the result will be an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Arkadiy!

Comment: Yep...you're right. I'll use List instead. @Holger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need introduce a factory to create the `MonitoredData`, in example I'm using a `Function` to create a `MonitoredData` from `String[]`:

```
Function<String[],MonitoredData> factory = data->{
   DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   try{
     return new MonitoredData(format.parse(data[0]),format.parse(data[1]),data[2]);
     //                       ^--startingTime       ^--finishingTime      ^--label
   }catch(ParseException ex){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
   }
};
```

**THEN** your code operate on a stream should be like below, and you don't need casting the result by using [Collectors#toCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
list = stream.map(line -> line.split("\t\t")).map(factory::apply)  
             .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```